# Use std::random_shuffle with std::array

Tags: c++, stl, c++11, std

I have code as such:

```
typedef intptr_t ptr_t;

const int num_elements = 100;
ptr_t *pstr = (ptr_t *)malloc(sizeof(ptr_t) * num_elements);
std::array<ptr_t,num_elements> *parray = new (pstr) std::array<ptr_t,num_elements>;
```

I'd like to be able to shuffle elements 1 to num_elements-2 , so I thought to use std::shuffle.

```
auto s = parray->begin()++;
auto e = parray->end()--;
std::random_shuffle ( s, e );
```

I get a complaint that there is no overloaded function for this.
I'm feeling really stupid at my inability to see what I'm doing wrong. How do I do this right?

EDIT: due to answers and feedback, it has changed to

```
auto s = parray->begin();
s++;
auto e = parray->end();
std::random_shuffle ( s, e );
```

However, on the 'auto e' I get: 'auto' differs in levels of indirection from 'int *'

Comment: I've never seen iterator arithmetic applied to `end()` before. Also, you want to `++` the `s`, not the temporary from `begin()`.

Comment: A quick note: the `++` and `--` have no effect on the values of `s` and `e`, because it happens after the assignment. Moreover, it's done on a temporary, which then is promptly discarded.

Comment: Why are you doing it so complicated? Just use `new[]`.

Comment: Shouldn't `ptr_t pstr` be `ptr_t* pstr`?

Comment: @zvrba: Do not ever, ever use `new[]`. That's so wrong, it's unbelievable.

Comment: Another quick note: If you are dynamically allocating space, why not use a `std::vector` to do that? The idea behind `std::array` is to *not* have to allocate space on the heap.

Comment: @BoPersson that syntax for std::array is placement new. It places it "over" the already-allocated array. It is perfectly valid behavior and it is meant to work this way. The actual code doesn't do things in this order, it gets an array and then tries to use random_shuffle on it, but first it needs to 'convert' it, which std::array does.

Comment: I'd be the first to recommend using std::array over raw arrays, but trying to 'convert' a raw array to std::array like that doesn't seem like the best idea. E.g. I think it's technically possible that sizeof(ptr_t) * num_elements isn't the right size. Just do `std::random_shuffle(pstr+1, pstr+num_elements-1);`

Comment: @DeadMG It's "wrong" if you need babysitting, in which case you shouldn't be using C++ anyway. In any case it's far better than getting memory through malloc and using placement new.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In answer to your direct question:  I believe your error is using the post increment operators, which return their original value before incrementing.  Since `std::array` iterators are basically pointers, try

```
auto s = parray->begin() + 1;
auto e = parray->end() - 1;
```

Edit:
Now, as for the rest.  Why on earth are you doing it that way?  Have you considered
`std::vector<int> arr(100)` to create a dynamic array of 100 elements?  It has similar capabilities, without all of the direct manipulation of pointers?

Edit 2: After reading your comments, I realize the issue is that you're trying to shuffle an array you were given as a pointer.  In that case, I wouldn't do the placement new at all.  Assuming you have the pointer in `pstr`, this should work.

```
std::random_shuffle(pstr +1, pstr + num_elements - 1);
```

This works because simple pointers in an array will work as random access iterators for the purposes of the algorithm library.

Comment: edited question. and, as to why I'm using direct pointers, it's a long story, but it makes sense for my usage.

Comment: Well, that works. Thanks! Still curious to know why it wouldn't work with array iterators, but you fixed my problem

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave : There are no array iterators -- `std::array<T>::begin()` and `std::array<T>::end()` both return `T*`.

Comment: @ildjarn in all existing implementations? Yeah. But the spec leaves `std::array<T,N>::iterator` and `std::array<T,N>::const_iterator` implementation-defined.

Comment: @R.MartinhoFernandes : I meant in the OP's code/compiler, as evidenced by his compiler errors.

Answer (score 2):

Even if the compiler allowed it, your code wouldn't do what you want. You're trying to use post increment/decrement on the values being returned from `begin()`/`end()`, so you'd still be assigning the original values to `s` and `e`, then (if possible) incrementing/decrementing the temporaries they're returning. You apparently want to change the values being assigned.

```
auto s= parray->begin();
auto e= parray->end();

++s;
--e;

std::random_shuffle(s, e);
```

Or, since you apparently have random access iterators anyway:

```
 std::random_shuffle(parray->begin()+1, parray->end()-1);
```

I'm not sure why you're dynamically allocating an `std::array` -- that seems to pretty much defeat the point of using `std::array` to start with.

Comment: edited question to do as you say, doesn't work. see edit. however, std::array being placement new'd on top of an array is part of the simplification for this question, it isn't the actual order of code

Comment: @std''OrgnlDave: the problem you're citing in the edit sounds a lot like a compiler problem -- the whole point of `auto` is that it should generate the correct type to match the value being assigned. If so, it's probably easiest to change it to `int *s=...; int *e=...;`